# How to resolve the problem related to "Whitelabel Error Page" in a Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to execute my new Spring Boot application.
The first two classes are:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class UbbioneApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UbbioneApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

then the servlet Initializer class

```
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(UbbioneApplication.class);
    }
}
```

But when I am used to run my application by writing `mvn spring-boot:run` in the console, I have this message appearing:

> Whitelabel Error Page

Could you help me please how to resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean `run my application by the message`?

Comment: I'd like to say that I use the command : mvn spring-boot:run to run the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have an answer:

I created a controller to my application and I updated my code as following:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"Name_controller_path"})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Then my controller will look like this:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class Appcontroller {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String home() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Then use this path to view your execution: http://localhost:8080/home.